# div container height too tall after div transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has "pages" inside a container. The number of pages could be 1-10 but because of that I can't have a specific height.

I have the container fit to the size of the screen aka the div. This works great, however, when I shrink the window to be smaller than what the original div's height was, the container's height remains the same and leaves A LOT of white space.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[My jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6xjDq/4/) | [jsfiddle full screen](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6xjDq/4/show/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="zoom">
        <div id="formform">
            <div class="formContainer"></div>
            <div class="formContainer"></div>
            <div class="formContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px dashed grey;
}
#formform::after {
    display: block;
    content:'';
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#formform {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:940px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-470px;
    border:0px solid red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
}
.formContainer {
    position:relative;
    margin : 0 auto 15px auto;
    width:940px;
    padding:0;
    height:1178px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
zoomProject(0);

$(window).resize(function (e) {
    zoomProject(0);
});

function zoomProject(percent) {
    $maxWidth = $("#zoom").width();

    if (percent == 0) percent = $maxWidth / 920;

      $("#formform").css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ')'
      });
}
```

Comment: "however, when I shrink the window to be smaller than what the original div's height was" what is the original div here..?

Comment: @TJ When my div get's `transform`ed smaller than what it was originally. Shrink the window in my example, and you will see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The white space seems to be because you are only scaling the x-axis, you should scale the y-axis as well in order to keep aspect ratio

```
  $("#formform").css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + percent + ', '+percent+)',
        '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ', '+percent+)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + percent + ', '+percent+)'
});
```

**UPDATE: CSS**

```
 #container {
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px dashed grey;
}
#formform::after {
    display: block;
    content:'';
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#formform {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:940px;

    border:0px solid red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
    -ms-transform-origin: top center;
}
.formContainer {
    position:relative;
    margin : 0 auto 15px auto;
    width:940px;
    padding:0;
    height:1178px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @The4thIceman but this unforunatly did not work.

Comment: @bryan - is your goal for all the <div>s to re-size proportionally to the screen as it re-sizes? or for the inner <div>s to remain the same size and the 'container' div re-size around them? either way you will have to reset the height of #container to adjust for re-sizing.

Comment: I just don't want there to scroll downy to empty space. Your code, in theory, is what I want.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was hoping for a css alternative solution but this will do. @The4thIceman

Comment: @bryan - I also made some changes to the css to make it look that way. I will post the css I used.

Comment: there seems to be something wrong in your js syntax. It didn't actually scale. `.formContainer` must have a width of 940px;

Comment: @bryan - this is jsfiddle without any javascript. Everything re-sizes on my end. What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/6xjDq/41/embedded/result/

Comment: you have width set to `width:940;` not `940px`. The point is for it to scale and keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: if you want to keep the aspect ratio, then you need to y-axis argument to the scale(x,y) function of transform.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overflow:hidden; on the CSS rule for the outer container where your different divs will load?

```
overflow:hidden;
```

will adjust the height to whatever the height of the child.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naxus28/D5qRE/4/

You will see that the outer div (purple border) adapts to whatever div you load inside it.

Hope this addresses your problem.